# R-squared for multivariate regression

Tags: r-squared, vector-autoregression, multivariate-regression

I have an output of recalibrated VARX model, which means for each 500 points of my data set I have trained a model and predicted the next month values using that model. Then, I have trained another model on the data points from 21 to 521 and predicted the next 21 days and so on. I have an output as:

[image]

How can I compute the $R^2$ for this model?

I compute it as `cor(df)^2` which gives me an output as:

[image]

I take the values of `Real.X#` from rows and `forc.varx.X#` from columns, which gives me an 5x5 matrix. I am not sure how to interpret this though. Should I only look at the diagonal of this matrix?

Comment: How do you define the $R^2$ for a multivariate regression? Would you be interested in $R^2$ values for each equation?

Comment: @RichardHardy I have put my output in the main question.